# Why does a project with "net8.0-windows" TargetFramework create a "net7.0" runtime subdirectory?

Tags: .net-8.0

We have several .csproj files in a solution that recently had their `TargetFramework` property updated from `net6.0-windows` to `net8.0-windows`.

Under the old value, the output directory would be populated with additional runtime files under `.\runtimes\win\lib\net6.0`.

Now, however, the runtimes are appearing under `.\runtimes\win\lib\net7.0`, and not the `.\runtimes\win\lib\net8.0` subdirectory that we expected.

We're building with Visual Studio 17.9.2 and .NET SDK 8.0.202.

While the new build artefacts can be deployed and work fine, I'm keen to understand the reason for the apparent mismatch in runtime directories.